# Retorno JSON com WEBAPI

Tags: c#, json

Estou criando uma `WebApi` onde o retorno dele e o seguinte.

```
[{
    "$id": "1",
    "Operadora": {
        "$id": "2",
        "Contato": [{
            "$ref": "1"
        }, {
            "$id": "3",
            "Operadora": {
                "$ref": "2"
            },
            "id": 5,
            "telefone": "99999-9999          ",
            "cor": "yeloow              ",
            "data": "2017-01-23T00:00:00",
            "id_operadora": 1,
            "nome": "Fernando                                          "
        }],
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "Vivo                ",
        "codigo": 15,
        "categoria": "Movel                         ",
        "preco": "1         "
    },
    "id": 1,
    "telefone": "99999-9999          ",
    "cor": "blue                ",
    "data": "2017-01-23T00:00:00",
    "id_operadora": 1,
    "nome": "Jose                                              "
}, {
    "$ref": "3"
}, {
    "$id": "4",
    "Operadora": {
        "$id": "5",
        "Contato": [{
            "$ref": "4"
        }],
        "id": 3,
        "nome": "CLARO               ",
        "codigo": 21,
        "categoria": "Movel                         ",
        "preco": "1         "
    },
    "id": 6,
    "telefone": "99999-9999          ",
    "cor": "yeloow              ",
    "data": "2017-01-23T00:00:00",
    "id_operadora": 3,
    "nome": "Carlos                                            "
}]
```

estou utilizando `WebAPI` com `Entity Framework from database`.

Estas foras as classes geradas automaticamente .

```
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Contato
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string telefone { get; set; }
    public string cor { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> data { get; set; }
    public int id_operadora { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }

    public virtual Operadora Operadora { get; set; }
  }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Operadora
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Operadora()
    {
        this.Contato = new HashSet<Contato>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> codigo { get; set; }
    public string categoria { get; set; }
    public string preco { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Contato> Contato { get; set; }
 }
}
```

O meu problema e o seguinte,tenho uma `foreign key` para `Operadora`, quando no cadastro do contato eu coloco o mesmo `id_operadora` o `JSON` retorna todos que estão com o mesmo `id_operadora` todos no mesmo `NO`.

alguem sabe , como poderia resolver isso ? cada cadastro no seu NO ?

Answer (score 1):

O que está acontecendo é que você possui uma referência cíclica no seu mapeamento (1 contato possui uma operadora e uma operadora possui uma collection de contatos).

Basicamente, você pode resolver de duas maneiras:

A primeira e mais indicada é utilizar o atributo [`JsonIgnore`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) na collection dentro da classe de contato e onde mais você desejar que seja ignorado pelo serializador JSON.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public partial class Operadora
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Operadora()
    {
        this.Contato = new HashSet<Contato>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> codigo { get; set; }
    public string categoria { get; set; }
    public string preco { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Contato> Contato { get; set; }
 }
}
```

A segunda que também é útil mais não recomendo, é dividida em duas etapas:

Configurar o seu DbContext para não criar classes de proxy.

```
DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

E configurar o serializador JSON para ignorar referencias cíclicas:

```
public static void ConfigWebApi(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var formatters = config.Formatters;
    formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter);

    var jsonSettings = formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
    jsonSettings.Formatting = Formatting.None;
    jsonSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

    formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
    formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
 }
```

Da forma que está, além de gerar retorno desnecessário de informações no JSON, você poderá criar um gargalo na sua Web API, recomendo fortemente ler o [e-book gratuito da Red Gate que apresenta 25 dicas para melhorar a performance de aplicações ASP.NET](http://assets.red-gate.com/community/books/25-secrets-for-faster-asp-dotnet.pdf).